# Accessing localStorage in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So, the error is simple, i'm new to next.js, and i need to access localStorage, but i can't, this is how the issue looks like

[image]

I tried to search for an answer, but couldn't find one, this is my code so far

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // redirect if already log in/haven't log in

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth")));
  }

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <AuthContext>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AuthContext>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

What can i do to access it ? Thanks for your time !

Comment: Does `window.localStorage` also return undefined?

Comment: Yop, it returns unefined

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` operator returns a string. So you need to compare it to a string if the strict equality operator `===` is used.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
 //
}
```